# Correlation and causation data

Tags: statistics, correlation

What are some real life examples (data) in which high correlation:

1) implies  causation
2) doesn't imply causation.

I know that there is a lot of data out there of weird correlations, like divorce rate and consuption of margarine, but the problem with this data is, that we don't really know if one is caused by the other, because nobody tested it, so we cannot strictly say that they're unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

One causative example could be the link between emotional wellbeing and grade-point average. A decrease in mental health can easily be linked to lower focus/motivation for grades.

You could look at drowning rates and ice cream sales. One does not directly cause the other, however they are both activities that increase in frequency during **summer**.

There is no simple way to determine whether A *causes* B without knowing real information.